# Deleting array values based on multiple factors

Tags: php

I have a php array in my project filled with paths to files and folders. I'd like to remove certain elements from the array with pre-definied criteria. In my case I want to remove all files with `.min.` in their names as well as all files with the ending `.test`.

I'm currently running through each key of the array and checking with `strpos` if the value contains my search filters. So basically using foreach within a foreach.

Is there an better method on doing so?

```
$filter = array(".min.", ".test");

$files = array(
    "/var/www/apps/files/index.php",
    "/var/www/apps/files/js/app.bundle.js",
    "/var/www/apps/files/dat/data.test",
    "/var/www/apps/files/css/custom.css",
    "/var/www/apps/files/css/custom.min.css"
);
```

Comment: Other ways will do "foreach inside foreach" too but only under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `preg_filter`  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php

with `RegEx` `Pattern` filtering `.min.js` `.min.css` and `.test` files

```
$pattern = '/^.*(?<!.min.css|.min.js|.test)$/';
$filtered = preg_filter( $pattern,'$0', $files);
print_r($filtered);
```